# Why one of the cores is running full on (100%) during development?

Tags: linux, python, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage

I'm developing an app (Python) which uses face recognition and OpenCV libraries.
I can see even after the app finished processing one of the cores keeps running full on
for another 10 mins or so.

Python has built-in garbage collection to keep up with unused variables and to wipe them
out to free memory.

Are there any extra steps I may need to do ? I can't have this in production.

below I'm sharing CPU consumption as well as overview of process manager which isn't revealing any outstanding heavy processes.

[image: one core is running 100% for about 10 mins after finished using features]

[image: Processe manager isn't revealing any outstanding CPU consumption]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, your system monitor doesn't show everything.

Use `top` or one of its [alternatives](https://www.linuxlinks.com/AlternativesToTop/) to see which process is using your processor.

BTW it's strange, that the loaded processor is not cycled by kernel. It should be as one of the processors is loaded then is periodically changed to the next in the queue.

Comment: I find it odd too. I'm gonna install `top` to see if it will give me some insight into what's happening.

Comment: OK joke is on me because it's `timeshift`. It's still weird though because it supposed to be running only once a day.

Comment: I don't know what you're using but top is super standard and never seen it not installed "onboard".

Comment: Yeah I didn't know it already came with Ubuntu. I just typed in `top` into terminal and it showed me that `timeshift` was eating up one of my cores periodically. We learn every day, don't we ?